# Git serve: I would like it that simple

Tags: windows, git, mercurial

I want to know how to simply publish over http = much like [Mercurial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial)'s hg serve! On the Windows/work box do this:

```
git serve
```

and then on the Linux box SIMPLY go:

```
git clone http://project project
```

finished.

Comment: Are you aware that cloning a git-svn clone of an svn repo is tricky? http://subtlegradient.com/articles/2008/04/22/cloning-a-git-svn-clone

Comment: Why not just install svn on your linux notebook ad use check out from the project repository directly?  Git may be the new hotness, but it really seems like you're making your life unnecessarily complicated in this particular case.

Comment: bendin no i didnt know it was tricky, as im setting up the environment now im glad you spoke up...

Comment: Firstly: my notebook is not allowed onto this vpn, so I cannot access the svn directly.
secondly: I want to commit to my own repository, the whole point of using git is so I can do local commits, branch and painlessly merge. I find using svn now rather cramping.

Comment: If you have python installed, a simple `git instaweb -d python` could be nough (with Git 2.21, Feb. 2019): see [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54971723/6309)

Answer (score 198, accepted):

Navigate into your project and start git-daemon with the following switches:

```
cd project
git daemon --reuseaddr --base-path=. --export-all --verbose
```

This tells git-daemon to serve up all projects inside the current directory (which I assume is the project directory containing the .git/ folder). It also tells it to re-use the same address if you shut it down and start it back up too fast.

You can put this into a batch script with an easy to remember name like "gitserve", so you don't need to type it all out again. As suggested in some of the comments, in recent versions of Git you can [add an alias to the Git config](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases#Serve_repo_on_the_spot):

```
[alias]
    serve = !git daemon --reuseaddr --verbose --base-path=. --export-all ./.git
```

Once that's done on the server (your Windows box), you can do:

```
git serve
```

git-daemon uses the git:// protocol for transport, so on the client (your Linux box), you would need to do:

```
git clone git://123.456.789.111/ project
```

Comment: You can add the command as an alias to you .gitconfig file as described here: http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/Aliases#Serverepoonthespot

Comment: that should be
http://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases#Serve_repo_on_the_spot

Comment: If you start git deamon in background mode, it may not work with --verbose option.

Comment: I think it's important to note that although `git daemon` allows for remote access by other git clients, it lacks the Web interface that `hg serve` provides.

Comment: And if you get `git: 'daemon' is not a git-command` you need to upgrade your git installation.

Comment: make serve an alias in your .gitrc like : `serve = !git daemon --reuseaddr --verbose  --base-path=. --export-all ./.git`

Comment: @Aeon, it seems URLs have changed and it's now https://git.wiki.kernel.org/articles/a/l/i/Aliases.html

Comment: Also, you need the `--enable=receive-pack` parameter if you wish to enable pushes. [[Source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/792611/receive-pack-service-not-enabled-for-git)] I've documented this a bit on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mx4492/1b144418911b48824919)

Comment: What can you do if you have multiple repos?

Answer (score 14):

Rather than write your own batch script, use [gitjour](http://github.com/chad/gitjour/tree/master).  It knows how to start git daemon correctly and will broadcast the clone URL via mDNS so you can do `gitjour show` on the linux box and copy and paste.

Also a good article with an overview of gitjour and a number of other similar tools from Dr. Nic, [What is *jour and why they are killer apps for RailsCamp08](http://drnicwilliams.com/2008/06/18/what-is-gitjour-gemjour-starjour/).

Answer (score 13):

If you just want to expose the repository with a web browser

[git-instaweb](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-instaweb)

```
$ git instaweb -d apache2 --start
$ lynx localhost:1234
```

Comment: it says `lighttpd not found. Install lighttpd or use --httpd to specify another httpd daemon.`

Comment: @syedrakib You'll need to have lighttpd installed, or apache2, or something else. Personally I use `git instaweb -d webrick` on OS X, because webrick comes with Ruby, which is preinstalled on OS X.

Comment: This tool doesn't seem to be Windows compatible. As the poster was asking for a Windows tool, that is an important factor for this answer.

Answer (score 13):

Currently using two aliases - serve and hub. Serve for read-only share and hub for read/write share:

```
[alias]
  serve = !git daemon --base-path=. --export-all --reuseaddr --informative-errors --verbose
  hub = !git daemon --base-path=. --export-all --enable=receive-pack --reuseaddr --informative-errors --verbose
```

Also, there is more detailed tutorial about sharing via git daemon: http://l.rw.rw/git-daemon .

Answer (score 9):

Here is an alternative way. You will need python installed.

- run `git update-server-info`
- go to the `.git` directory
- run `python -mSimpleHTTPServer`

(just create an alias in your gitconfig)

Now you can pull the repo with `git pull http://HOST_NAME:8000/`

PS: when usingthe  git daemon solution you can set `--base-path=.git` so the url is `git://HOST/`

Answer (score 1):

Git 2.21 (Feb. 2019) allows you to combine python and [`git instaweb`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-instaweb):

See [commit 2eb14bb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2eb14bb2d41b27d23120206bbe3d409a83cf042f) (28 Jan 2019) by [Arti Zirk (`artizirk`)](https://github.com/artizirk).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit abf39e3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/abf39e3396f597adfac1f37a3b5706950dadfec3), 05 Feb 2019)</sup>

> ### `git-instaweb`: add Python builtin `http.server` support
>
> With this patch it is possible to launch `git-instaweb` by using Python `http.server` CGI handler via `-d python` option.
>
> `git-instaweb` generates a small wrapper around the `http.server` (in `GIT_DIR/gitweb/`) that address a limitation of the CGI handler where CGI scripts have to be in a `cgi-bin` subdirectory and directory index can't be easily changed. To keep the implementation small, `gitweb` is running on url `/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi` and an automatic
>   redirection is done when opening `/`.
>
> The generated wrapper is compatible with both Python 2 and 3.
>
> Python is by default installed on most modern Linux distributions
>   which enables running `git instaweb -d python` without needing
>   anything else.

Answer (score 0):

git-webui is a git extension which provides a web based user interface and the ability to clone/pull from other computers

https://github.com/alberthier/git-webui

```
$ cd my_git_repo
$ git webui
```

Other people can

```
$ git clone http://<ip-of-your-computer>:8000/ repoclone
```

or

```
$ git pull http://<ip-of-your-computer>:8000/
```

Comment: I just tried with it blindly.  I am able to git clone but not able to access the webgui. It looks the browser is waiting for a response from your server.

Answer (score 0):

Add following lines in .git/config

```
[instaweb]
               local = true
               httpd = webrick
               port = 4231
```

then execute

```
git instaweb
```