# 'receive-pack': service not enabled for './.git'

Tags: git

(Solved already, I'm writing this for the next guy)

I was running git daemon on one computer and tried synchronizing with another.

On computer A, I ran:

```
git daemon --reuseaddr --base-path=. --export-all --verbose
```

On computer B, I ran:

```
git clone git://computerA/.git source # worked
cd source
git pull # worked
git push # failed with "fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly"
```

On computer A, the daemon output is:

```
[5596] Connection from 127.0.0.1:2476
[5596] Extended attributes (16 bytes) exist <host=localhost>
[5596] Request receive-pack for '/.git'
[5596] 'receive-pack': service not enabled for './.git'
[5444] [5596] Disconnected (with error)
```

I'm going to post the soultion I found. If you have a more complete answer, please go ahead and add it.

Comment: anyone using msysgit daemon on windows 'wanna know about the `sendpack.sideband` config-option at https://github.com/msysgit/git/issues/101#issuecomment-46114024 or alternatively use [Git-1.7.4.rc1.3197.gbf965](https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=457#c62) (a [more direct link](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=624606b9c3176d53&id=624606B9C3176D53!4848&authkey=!ANl5kSH_bExkzrk) here)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Simply run

```
git daemon --reuseaddr --base-path=. --export-all --verbose --enable=receive-pack
```

(on computer A, instead of the original `git daemon` command), and the push works.

Note that you have to then run

```
git reset --hard
```

on computer A to make it "see" the changes from computer B.

#### Post Script

The problem with doing a hard reset is that it overwrites whatever local changes you had on computer A.

Eventually I realized it would make much more sense to have a separate repository (a [bare clone](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#setting-up-a-public-repository)) that doesn't have any files in it, then have computer B push to it and computer A pull from it. This way it can work both ways and merge all the changes in a smooth fashion. You can even have two bare clones, one on each computer, and push-pull between them.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to not have to run `git reset --hard` after a push to see the changes?

Comment: Depends on why you don't want to run it. If you just want to minimize typing, you can set up a hook (check out http://utsl.gen.nz/git/post-update for an example). Otherwise, see my PS.

Comment: I am using the other (non bare) repository as a backup on a mounted NAS. I could set up a simple backup script but that had some other problems. I'll check out the the hook thing and your script. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Rohit If you're having issues pushing to a non-bare repository, try checking out another branch before pushing. If you're just using it as a backup, you'll always be able to check out your original branch in the future. I guess we don't really understand your problem domain. Maybe ask your question more fully in it's own Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Can you not `git stash` your local changes, then do a hard reset and pop your stash?

Answer (score 24):

I encountered this error, but the solution seems different for those using git-http-backend. (git push/pull/clone over http instead of ssh or git)

This must be done on the remote server, and is best done on creation. 
**(last line can be run independently if repo already exists / is in use)**

```
$ mkdir eddies  # MAKE folder for repo
$ chown -R eddie:websrv eddies/  #ensure apache (webserver) can access it
$ cd eddies/
$ git --bare init --shared
Initialized empty shared Git repository in /var/git/eddies/
$ ls
branches  config  description  HEAD  hooks  info  objects  refs
$ git config --file config http.receivepack true
```

Comment: YOu can also add SetEnv REMOTE_USER=$REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER to your apache config aparrently to get around this command.

Comment: See the full solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947530/git-push-fatal-failed/7177690#7177690

Comment: This is the solution that solved my issue (had existing local repo, created bare remote repo on windows server, trying to push via http, getting 403 error)

Answer (score 6):

I have some issue with the git reset --hard so here is my alternative solution.

On the local cloned repo make a branch

```
git checkout -b my_new_branch
```

on the remote origin repo enable the `receive-pack` service

```
git daemon --reuseaddr --base-path=. --export-all --verbose --enable=receive-pack
```

push the new branch to remote origin

```
git push origin my_new_branch
```

merge the new branch on origin with

```
git merge my_new_branch
```