# Why does a "git push" just hang there indefinitely using MySysGit 1.7.4?

Tags: git

I tried small experiments with Ruby and Rails, and would like to push and pull from the Mac to PC and vice verse.

So I installed what the Git's website's standard recommended Git on PC (MySysGit 1.7.4), and run

```
git daemon --reuseaddr --base-path=. --export-all --verbose --enable=receive-pack
```

either on the Mac or PC (to start a Git server), and then, on the PC, I cloned and add a file, and commit, and then do a

```
git push git://192.168.1.31/ master
```

now it will print out the following and just hang there indefinitely:

```
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4)
```

I tried it on another PC, and it is the same thing.  How can this be fixed?

(I am using the command to run the server from question: ['receive-pack': service not enabled for './.git'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792611/receive-pack-service-not-enabled-for-git))

Comment: I had the same problem just now. All I did was let it do its thing for a few minutes.... and it worked. This could happen by simply having network issues at that time.

Answer (score 47):

They have just released a version that allows a config option to stop git hanging.

Fix is for https://github.com/msysgit/git/issues/101 in release https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases/tag/Git-1.9.4-preview20140611

You can fix it by setting

```
git config --global sendpack.sideband false
```

Comment: I wanted to note: set this on the sending side.

Answer (score 9):

Apparently due to a bug in msysgit, that prevents it from pushing to git-daemon.

http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=457

I was stuck on this myself. You can either install cygwin git (worked for me) or use ssh-based repo (worked for me as well, but i installed the remote repo on linux and used gitolite)

Comment: If anybody, like me, comes around and thinks "Well, it has almost been three years now, "push" is going to work nowadays": No. Still an issue, albeit "closed": https://github.com/msysgit/git/issues/101

Comment: Yup, I just fell prey to it right now :( 

At least the issue is "open" now.. but I guess they aren't going to fix it any time soon...