# Git push is stuck and does not throw any errors

Tags: git, gitlab

I am trying to push after merging a temporary branch into the master. 
But 'git push' is not doing its job. It does all the local processing but gets stuck at the last step. How can I resolve this?

I did the following:

```
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff dev_08_15
git commit -a -m "dev_08_15 Merge commit"
git push origin master
```

And now git is stuck at this place. Below is the output I get.

```
Counting objects: 61, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (19/19), done.
Writing objects: 100% (28/28), 2.20 KiB, done.
Total 28 (delta 14), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

I can pull the changes which others are pushing. But I can't push any of my changes now.

Comment: What you see when you do `git status`?

Comment: What does `git push -v --dry-run` say?

Comment: git push -v --dry-run gives the following lines:
    `Pushing to <my git repo> \n
    To <my git repo> \n
    da2e4ae..c33a92c  master -> master`

git status gives:
    `# On branch master \n
    # Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 66 commits. \n
    nothing to commit (working directory clean) \n`

Comment: @deepng - What OS are you on? If you're using Windows, you might try the answer listed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520329/why-does-a-git-push-just-hang-there-indefinitely-using-mysysgit-1-7-4

Comment: Run `git gc`, then check if your "origin" is pointing to right URL (git remote -v) and you have write access to it. If everything is OK then your push will work