# git push from eclipse to a bare repository gets rejected

Tags: eclipse, git, push, egit

I have bare repository on my PC (running windows 7) - Machine A - and I'm using the command:

```
git daemon --export-all --verbose --enable=receive-pack
```

to run the git daemon.

From another maching (mac) - Machine B - I was able to push from the upstream using egit (from eclipse).

My problem is that I'm unable to pull the repository. When I try this, it gives me "rejected" on Machine B. On machine A, I get the following:

> [952] [1976] Disconnected
>   [5868] Connection from 192.168.1.102:56643
>   [5868] Extended attributes (20 bytes) exist 
>   [5868] Request upload-pack for '/somerepository/.git'
>   [952] [5868] Disconnected
>   [3088] Connection from 192.168.1.102:56645
>   [3088] Extended attributes (20 bytes) exist 
>   [3088] Request receive-pack for '/somerepository/.git'

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not totally sure but don't you need a `base-path` for daemon.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/792611/receive-pack-service-not-enabled-for-git could help here. Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501125/remote-git-daemon-immediately-disconnects-my-client-on-a-git-pull

Comment: thanks guys for your replies. base-path seems to be used for mapping relative paths, and it is not mandatory. I also checked the other 2 links where --enable=receive-pack seems to bring me a step closer to the solution, but not completely solved yet