# git equivalent of 'hg serve'?

Tags: git, mercurial

Is there some sort of addon you can use to have a git equivalent of the Mercurial

```
hg serve
```

('hg serve' starts a local web-server which allows you to browse the repository history/branches etc)

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438163/whats-the-best-web-interface-for-git-repositories

Comment: @YounElan: I think this is a separate question. The question you link to is about setting up a GitHub clone locally whereas this question is about starting a short-term web server so that others can push/pull from you.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [`git instaweb`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-instaweb.html).

By default it uses `lighttpd`, but any other web server like `webrick` also should work.

I prefer webrick because it is much convenient (and I have `ruby` and `webrick` gem installed)

Examples:

```
# Starts a web server on port 1234 and opens up a web browser
git instaweb --httpd=webrick

# To stop webrick
git instaweb --httpd=webrick --stop
```

You should be able to configure the `instaweb` settings in your `.git/config` or `~/.gitconfig` and merely run `git instaweb --start` and `git instaweb --stop` to control instaweb:

```
[instaweb]
    local = true
    httpd = webrick
    port = 1234
    browser = chromium
```

UPDATE:

[git-webui](https://github.com/alberthier/git-webui) which [alberthier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1697414/alberthier) mentioned in his answer, is actually a much richer UI compared to the default `instaweb` and installation is also really straight-forward.

Comment: Excellent - thanks very much. I did use lightttpd instead of webrick and because I wanted to view the results outside the machine I was working on I set 'local = false'. Worked fine.

Comment: With git 2.1.1 on Cygwin, `git instaweb` yields `git: 'instaweb' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`

Answer (score 68):

For just browsing files and revisions `git instaweb` is the right solution.

In addition if you want to set-up an *ad-hoc* git server for sharing work (push/pull) with some colleagues (which `hg serve` also allows you to do), you can use:

```
git daemon --reuseaddr --base-path=. --export-all --verbose --enable=receive-pack
```

Your colleagues will use it with something like:

```
git clone git://<ip-address>/.git project
```

Addition 1:

If you want to be able to *push* to this server, you need to add the `--enable=receive-pack` option (Thanks to Dominik below).

Addition 2:

It just happened to me so I add it to the answer :-), if you are using a *Redhat-based* Linux distribution (RHEL, CentOS, etc.) and have an error `"git: 'daemon' is not a git command."`, then you need to install a seperate package for it:

```
sudo yum install git-daemon
```

Comment: Got `fatal: remote error: access denied or repository not exported: REPO` using the Git server. On server side: `'receive-pack': service not enabled for  DIR/REPO`.
The solution is to add `--enable=receive-pack` (see @itsadok's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/792621/1168315))

Comment: Thanks @Dominik, I will add this tip to the answer. Without this you can pull but not push.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as `hg serve` allow cloning.

Answer (score 9):

git-webui is a git extension which provides a web based user interface and the ability to clone/pull from other computers

https://github.com/alberthier/git-webui

```
$ cd my_git_repo
$ git webui
```

Other people can

```
$ git clone http://<ip-of-your-computer>:8000/ repoclone
```

or

```
$ git pull http://<ip-of-your-computer>:8000/
```

Comment: @alberthier - git-webui looks really good and installation is really straightforward as well :)