# How to pull a git repository on ubuntu without internet connection?

Tags: git, ubuntu, offline, git-pull

I want to use Git over the local network in our company because I don't have internet access in my computer. My friend has an internet connection and an ubuntu machine, he pushed some source codes to Git and I need to pull them without Internet connection and I also use ubuntu 14.04. 
Additionaly, I set up a repository with the command:

```
git init --bare
```

EDIT: Both machines are ubuntu, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: possible duplicate of [git equivalent of 'hg serve'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670692/git-equivalent-of-hg-serve)

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11792671/ using git-bundle to copy the repo. The [man page for git-bundle](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle) and http://stackoverflow.com/a/3639182/ show how to synchronize later if needed.

Comment: @Hasturkun is it possible to use git bundle without using sneakernet

Comment: @sosa: The main purpose of it is to allow offline transfers. You could e.g. create a bundle, put it somewhere accessible (e.g. downloading the bundle externally to a flash drive) and import it. You need some way of getting the bundle to the destination. If both machines are online in the same network, you can use `git clone` over ssh or rsync and skip all this.

Answer (score 3):

Ask your friend to create a windows share for the git repository.

Ensure that you have installed

```
apt-get install cifs-utils
```

create a mount dir

```
$ mkdir ~/my_friends_repo
```

mount the remote share using

```
$ sudo mount -t cifs -o username=USERNAME,password=PASSWORD \
      //your_friends_ip_or_computer_name/NAME_OF_SHARE ~/my_friends_repo
```

Now you can either clone it

```
git clone ~/my_friends_repo my_friends_repo_clone
```

or add it to your existing repo as another remote repository and pull his changes

```
git remote add my_friends_repo ~/my_friends_repo
git pull my_friends_repo master
```

Comment: I also added another answer that might be more simple http://stackoverflow.com/a/26159184/974186

Answer (score 2):

In addition to my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26158007/974186)...

Your friend can use `git daemon` on his windows machine to export the repository

On the windows machine do this in the git bash

```
git daemon --export-all --reuseaddr --verbose --enable=receive-pack --base-path=PATH_TO_THE_REPOSITORY
```

On your ubuntu machine you can than clone the repo

```
git clone git://your_friends_ip_or_computer_name REPO_CLONE_NAME
```

or add it to your existing repo as another remote repository and pull his changes

```
git remote add my_friends_repo  git://your_friends_ip_or_computer_name
git pull my_friends_repo master


touch git-daemon-export-ok
```

Answer (score 1):

### Basics

A git repository is not much more than a box. You can put your code in in it (commit), you can send a copy of the content to another (remote) box (push), and you can fetch the content from another box to your own box (pull).

If your friend pushed his content to some box in the internet (like github) and you cannot access that location from your host, this box is not helpful in your case.

You have a few choices:

- Pull directly from your friends repository (The "box" he used to push to github.)
- Ask him to directly push his repository to your host.
- Set up some repository somewhere in your network. (In this case he can push to that repository and you can afterwards pull from it.)

### Solution using a intermediate repository

As you are using ubuntu which already comes with ssh, maybe the easiest solution is setting up a new user on your box and create a bare repository there. Then you have a place to pull from an your friend can use that user to push to that repository.

You can do this like this:

```
sudo useradd -m gituser                     # create user
sudo -iu gituser git init --bare reponame   # create repository
sudo passwd gituser                         # set password for user
```

Afterwards your friend can push to it using `git push gituser@yourhost/reponame`. And you can get the pushed content with `git clone gituser@yourhost/reponame`.

### Solution using git-daemon

Another way is to use [git-daemon](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-daemon.html) on your friends host to serve his repository. In this case you can pull directly from his host. On windows type:

```
git daemon --base-path=PATH --export-all
```

where "PATH" is the local directory containing the repository. On ubuntu you can access that repository using

```
git clone git://friendshost/reponame
```

where "friendshost" is the hostname of your friends host, and "reponame" is the name of the directory containing the repository. For example if the repository is located at "C:\some\dir\repo" then "C:\some\dir" is the PATH and "repo" is the reponame.)

Answer (score -1):

This depends where your friend has his git repository located.

You can specify the location of remote origins in the .gitconfig file.
See this [link](http://www.gitguys.com/topics/the-configuration-file-remote-section/) for more details.