# git push fails with "fatal: remote error: access denied or repository not exported"

Tags: git

I'm new to `git`, and have a server that I have inherited. 
I have 2 remote repos that seem to have the same setup. The first one is used for productA and can be accessed remotely as follows:

```
git clone git://server/productA.git productA
touch newfile
git add newfile
git commit -a
git push
```

This is where I fail. productA works and productB fails with the following message:

> fatal: remote error: access denied or repository not exported: /productB.git

I have looked on the server and can't seem to find anything that sticks out as being different between the repositories. What am I missing?

Comment: I may have left out enough details for someone else to answer this but here is the solution I found while comparing the git config on the 2 projects. ProjectA had the following line in the server side projectA.git/config file:

[daemon]
    receivepack = true

I added this to the config for projectB and I was able to do the push after setting it.  I had the hardest time finding documentation for this. I'm not sure if this is just an old version of git or this config file is just not documented.

Comment: This looks like the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/792611/receive-pack-service-not-enabled-for-git (even though the error message is different)

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to move to sub-directory (e.g. **productA** in your sample), between **clone** and **touch**:

```
git clone git://server/productA.git productA
cd productA
touch newfile
```

Anyway, it won't fix your access issue; do you have access to the server permissions?

Maybe your user don't have the same permission on productA and on productB?

Or maybe the requirements to push are not the same (for instance, there could be some rules to push on the **master** branch).