# git: simplest way to share a repository between two laptops on a local network?

Tags: git

If my friend has a git repository on his laptop, and we are both connect to the same LAN, what's the absolute simplest way for me to clone that repository?

As far as I can tell, the options are:

- Getting SSH access to his machine
- Installing a web server and using `git instaweb`

But neither of these are *particularly* simple (or, at least, as simple as `hg serve`)… Is there anything better?

Comment: What machines are you both using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't remember what all the options mean, so it may take some playing, but I think git daemon does what you want.
I have had it work in the past.

Comment: Ah, yes, `git daemon` is what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

```
cd project
git daemon --reuseaddr --base-path=.git --export-all --verbose
```

To access: `git pull git://HOST/`

See answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/377293/794407

Answer (score 3):

For cloning only, you want to use `git daemon --export-all $PWD`  You can configure it to be read/write, but that is very insecure.

git-instaweb does not allow you to clone a repository.

Of course using github is a convenient way to share repositories without lots of configuration (though setting up an ssh server is usually not very difficult).

Comment: Ah, yes, `git daemon` looks like what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly point-and-click, but this might help:

[`http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way`](http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way)

Also, if you have access to his drive via any type of share (NFS, Samba, etc) then you can clone via the share name.

Oh, and there's also [`git-daemon`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-daemon.html).

Comment: Ah, yes, `git daemon` looks like what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering if laptops (behind NAT) could remotely address each other (with logical rather than hostnames) via XMPP, if a tunneling of SSH over XMPP existed. I found http://code.google.com/p/xmpp-ssh/ but it seems old and unloved, and not clear whether intermediate servers need to support the XMPP extensions it uses.