# Git daemon cloning error

Tags: git

All,

I'm following the instructions from [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/377293/724357) answer, to quickly serve up a repo. When I run `git clone git://ipAddr/.git project` I get this output:

```
remote: Counting objects: 124634, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (21253/21253), done.
Receiving objects: 100% (124634/124634), 101.62 MiB | 4.30 MiB/s, done.
fatal: read error: Invalid argument
Resolving deltas: 100% (96298/96298), done.
fatal: error in sideband demultiplexer
```

I've tried restarting the git daemon and cloning again, with no success. Some google searches lead me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4582965/724357) But the links are dead, and `git remote set-head` asks me for a branch name.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to have resolved itself. Since the machine I am cloning to has connectivity issues, my best guess is that I was getting a corrupted clone.