# How can I use git to push to a specific folder on my site?

Tags: git

I'd like to do the following:

- Create a local git repo, let's call it `~/my-awesome-app`
- create a folder on my site, let's call it `mysite.com/my-awesome-app`
- Be able to just push any changes I make on `~/my-awesome-app` to `mysite.com/my-awesome-app`

Can someone explain how I would set that up?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git serve: I would like it that simple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377213/git-serve-i-would-like-it-that-simple)

Comment: I don't think it's it's a duplicate. This question is asking to deploy to a directory. The other is asking about serving repositories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make `mysite.com/my-awesome-app` a git repository and set `receive.denyCurrentBranch` in it to `ignore` to allow pushing there but this is risky.

If I wanted to do this, I'd make a bare repository on my server which I could push my code into and then change the `update` hook to export the latest tree into `mysite.com/my-awesome-app` (and optionally restart the app). That way, the repository and the deployed copy are two different things.

Comment: So would the bare repo be somewhere outside the public html? and the update hook would just copy whatever is pushed into that forward into into the public folder? 

Out of curiosity, why would the first option be risky?

Comment: It would be outside `public_html` and it would use `git archive` rather than just "copy" the code. The first would be risky because pushing to a non-bare repo will not update the working copy. You'd have to set this up manually and that means chances for bugs.

Comment: Your second suggestion (to push to a bare repo on the server and use the update hook) was the direction I went. [This article](http://joemaller.com/990/a-web-focused-git-workflow/)  sealed the deal and gave me the hand-holding I needed to implement it being a total git novice.

Comment: Cool. Glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a git repo at **~/mysite.com** on your remote server? If so, like [James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/346740/james) and [Noufal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/229602/noufal-ibrahim) noted, *be careful, this sort of nesting can be problematic.*

Consider the following solution that should work whether it's nested or not:

1. Create the **my-awesome-app** repo outside of **~/mysite.com** (say at **~/my-awesome-app**).
2. Then **create a symbolic link** from **~/my-awesome-app/** to **~/mysite.com/my-awesome-app**.
3. And, to be safe, **add ~/mysite.com/my-awesome-app/** to the **~/mysite.com/.gitignore** file to exclude it from actions of the **~/mysite.com/** repo.

On the remote server, from shell:

```
mkdir ~/my-awesome-app/
ln -s ~/my-awesome-app/ ~/mysite.com/my-awesome-app
echo /my-awesome-app >> ~/mysite.com/.gitignore
```

When releasing commits from the local **my-awesome-app** branch to the remote server, I would **use the path ~/my-awesome-app** as the upload/relative directory rather than ~/mysite.com/my-awesome-app. This should save you from some cheeky IDE that tries to ascend the file structure looking for git repos.

Lastly, I would **consider adding a remote repo at ~/my-awesome-app** and not just sending file there via sftp/ftp or ssh without a repoo. This allows you to maintain a highly stable production environment while still being able to incoporate hotfixes back into your local dev copy using the scalable [gitflow](http://nvie.com/img/2009/12/Screen-shot-2009-12-24-at-11.32.03.png) method.

*There's a good discussion on gitflow by Vincent Driessen [here](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).*

---

**Update: Alternative approach to symbolic link**

Instead of a symbolic link (which has the potential to be deleted), you could make the changes to your site's config instead:

```
# creates the alias
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
     Alias /my-awesome-app /path/to/my-awesome-app/
</IfModule>

# allows people to access the path
<Directory /path/to/my-awesome-app/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Then when you do pushes, you should use /path/to/my-awesome-app/. I would still leave the **/my-awesome-app** line in ~/mysite.com/.gitignore just to be safe but without a symbolic link, git should never stumble accross the my-awesome-app repo at when acting on ~/mysite.com/.

Comment: Thanks very much for this answer, much appreciated. I am weighing all the options and continuing my exploration and will be back after I've sussed it all out.