# How to set git hook over HTTP protocol to Automate development on a remote server

Tags: git, http, nginx, automation, githooks

I am using git for version control and I want to Automate git to pull everything any of the collaborators push on release branch to a remote server automatically and if I want to do this over ssh, I have to add all of collaborators ssh-keys in my server, but I don't want to give them access to server, so I want to set this git hook over HTTP so that everyone can push to remote server via HTTP protocol

What I have done so far is set a git hook, and I use Nginx as web service and I have put the bare git repository in

```
/var/www/html/test_repo
```

and I set my git remote in local computer like this:

```
git remote add test http://ServerIp/test_repo
```

but it gives me this error:

```
fatal: repository 'http://ServerIp/test_repo/' not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need for your NGiNX to call `/usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend` in order for git to respond properly to clone/pull commands.

See for instance [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40313590/6309): it is best if you setup a folder in your URL path to track git repos.

```
    listen 80;
    server_name myhostname;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/git.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/git.error.log;
    gzip off;

    location ~ /git(/.*) {
      ...
    }
```

So the URL for your git repos would be http://ServerIp/git/test_repo, even though the `fastcgi_param GIT_PROJECT_ROOT` parameter would be `/var/www/html`