# nginx and git-http-backend 403 on push

Tags: git, nginx, push, fastcgi, http-status-code-403

I am trying to setup a git server with `stagit` for the front end, `git-http-backend` for the back and using `nginx` between everything. I've found a config that works on my server in [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36362218/13283549) answer (and by works, I mean nginx will serve html to any connection through a web browser, but lets me clone a repository if I use `git clone https://git.website.com/test.git`.

The problem I'm having, is that when I push this repository (whether that be from the server itself, or from my local computer) with an origin of `https://git.website.com/test.git` I receive a 403 error and I'm not sure why. Any ideas?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/ssl-private.key;

    root /srv/git;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/git.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/git.error.log;
    gzip off;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # static repo files for cloning over https
    location ~ ^.*/objects/([0-9a-f]+/[0-9a-f]+|pack/pack-[0-9a-f]+.(pack|idx))$ {
        root /srv/git;
    }

    # requests that need to go to git-http-backend
    location ~ ^.*/(HEAD|info/refs|objects/info/.*|git-(upload|receive)-pack)$ {
        root /srv/git;

        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME   /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO         $uri;
        fastcgi_param GIT_PROJECT_ROOT  $document_root;
        fastcgi_param GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL "";
        fastcgi_param REMOTE_USER $remote_user;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }   
}
```

I only started trying to use `git-http-backend` about two hours ago with multiple configs. It seems very difficult to get http to serve webpages normally but *also* allow for git to clone/push. Using a config as found [**here**](https://thenewstack.io/how-to-set-up-the-http-git-server-for-private-projects/) resulted in empty 200 OK responses...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much trial and error I've taken the config from [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40313590/13283549) answer and modified it to give me the following location rules:

```
location / {
    if ($arg_service = git-receive-pack) {
        rewrite (/.*) /git_write/$1 last;
    }

    if ($uri ~ ^/.*/git-receive-pack$) {
        rewrite (/.*) /git_write/$1 last;
    }

    if ($arg_service = git-upload-pack) {
        rewrite (/.*) /git_read/$1 last;
    }

    if ($uri ~ ^/.*/git-upload-pack$) {
        rewrite (/.*) /git_read/$1 last;
    }
}

# pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
}

location ~ /git_read/(.*) {
    include git-http-backend.conf;
}

# require auth to upload
location ~ /git_write/(.*) {
    auth_basic "Pushing to Git repositories is restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd;
    include git-http-backend.conf;
}
```

Where `/etc/nginx/git-http-backend.conf` reads:

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend;
fastcgi_param GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL "";
fastcgi_param GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /srv/git;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $1;
fastcgi_param REMOTE_USER $remote_user;
```

Problem solved.