# How can I use git à la P2P?

Tags: git, mercurial

In Mercurial, I can do something like:

```
> hg serve
**repository server now in localhost:8000**

> hostname
my_machine

> nslookup my_machine    
my_machine.myintranet.com

//gives my_machine.myintranet.com:8000 to colleague, from where he/she can push/pull
```

This allows me to not care about my blessed repo and make it possible to push from peer to another peer.

How do I do I fulfill that need in git?

P.S.: Optionally, I could enable the Mercurial zeroconf extension and then just do an hg paths outside of a repo context, which gets me a unique network URL for the repo which anyone could see.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [git instaweb](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-instaweb.html), it's a part of git.

Comment: Can you push/pull?, it doesn't appear to come with git version 1.7.11.msysgit.1

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377213/git-serve-i-would-like-it-that-simple